# why the last GUI element i declare is filling the whole panel?

Tags: java, swing, layout

`public class add extends JPanel {
    private JPanel add = new JPanel();
    JFrame frame;

    public add(){
                frame = new JFrame("Add");
                frame.setBounds(550, 300, 700,500);
                frame.setVisible(true); 

        JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Name");
        final JTextField nameField = new JTextField();
        frame.add(nameLabel);
        frame.add(nameField);
        nameLabel.setBounds(200, 40, 150, 30);
        nameField.setBounds(350, 40, 150, 30);

                ...

                                JButton registerButton =  new JButton("Salveaza");
        frame.add(registerButton);
        registerButton.setBounds(200,300,300, 30);
        registerButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

                    }




        });


    }


}`

and if i delete the JButton, than a label, which would be the last element, will fill the whole JPanel when i run the programm. 
what can i do so i can make it work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding components to a container, the JFrame's contentPane, that uses a BorderLayout as its default layout manager. When you do this and don't specify constants, the component gets added BorderLayout.CENTER, covering up any components added before.

- **Good Solution:** learn and use layout managers, including using nested JPanels, each using its own layout manager and components.
- **Bad Solution:** use null layout with absolute positioning. While to a newbie this seems the best way to create complex GUI's, the more you deal with Swing GUI creation, the more you will find that doing this will put your GUI in a straight-jacket, painting it in a very tight corner and making it very hard to extend or enhance. Just don't do this.

Comment: Could you help me solve my problem? i do not have that much time to learn now, sadly

Comment: @user3307020: I'll be glad to help, but I'm not going to do this for you -- no one will. It's time to put in the effort and learn to do this. Seriously, we're not here to do your homework for you just because you may be short on time, that's not what this site is all about. You can find the layout manager tutorials here: [laying out components in a container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: i don't want you to make my homework, i asked nicely if you could help me solve this problem, right now i do not have time to learn all about layout managers, and i tried by myself to solve the problem, it's not like i told you what i have to do and waited for you to make it for me. i told what my problem was, and i needed someone to help me, to tell me where i did wrong and what would be better to do.

Comment: @user3307020: Right now your question is, "why is my button filling my GUI", and this has been answered. If you need specific further help, then ask a specific question. Also as an aside, never say that you "don't have time to learn" please. This will only raise our hackles because again most of us are motivated by getting you to do the studying and learning.

Comment: ok, i'm sorry. Than i will rephrase my question, how can i make the last GUI element to stay in the boundaries that i wrote and not fill my whole JPanel. And also, i did write under the code:" what can i do so i can make it work properly?"

Comment: @user3307020: to stay within boundaries, you'd use a null layout. I do not recommend that you use it given my explanations above. Better to figure out just how you want the components to interact with each other graphically, and then choose the appropriate layout managers.